# Function with if statement

Tags: c

Hi I am new in the programming. I know how a function works and if statement, so I want to know how would I be able to write an if & else statement in a function and would display the answer to the user. there may not be any goto statements

The code is as follows:

```
  if(year < 1583) //considers if a year input is less than 1583 which is the starting year for this calendar
  {
       printf("\n\nPlease select a year after 1583 \n\n");
       goto YEAR;
       system("cls");
  }
  if(Leap_year(year))//if statement calls Leap Year function
  {
       printf("\t =======================  \n");
       printf("\t*  THIS IS A LEAP YEAR  *\n");      
       printf("\t =======================  \n\n"); 
  }
  else {
       printf("\t   =======================  \n");
       printf("\t*  THIS IS NOT A LEAP YEAR  *\n");
       printf("\t   =======================  \n\n"); 
  }
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Why is this tagged C#? This looks like C to me...

Comment: sorry i get confused with the type of c languages, but it is c

Comment: Can't you validate the input w/o that ugly GOTO?

Comment: @Icarus I'm pretty sure that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @ShadowChaser We need to know where the `YEAR` label is to know for sure what that `goto` is doing.

Comment: @trutheality I read the question too fast. I thought the issue was that he didn't know how to write the Leap_Year function.

Comment: @Icarus to be fair it looks like that is also a big part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's C or C#, you can solve this using a `while` loop.

```
do
{     
      // You need to prompt for year here.  Your code doesn't show how you do that.
      if (year < 1583)
      {
          printf("\n\nPlease select a year after 1583 \n\n");
          // Note: The user will never see the printf above if you clear the screen right after
          system("cls");
      }
} while (year < 1583);
```

Comment: how do i write this part in a  function form }
  if(Leap_year(year))//if statement calls Leap Year funtion
  {
       printf("\t =======================  \n");
       printf("\t*  THIS IS A LEAP YEAR  *\n");      
       printf("\t =======================  \n\n"); 
  }
  else {
       printf("\t   =======================  \n");
       printf("\t*  THIS IS NOT A LEAP YEAR  *\n");
       printf("\t   =======================  \n\n");

Comment: What do you mean by "in a function form"?  Do you want to separate that code out into a different function?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are looking for is to use more functions.

Consider:

```
// year == -1 means there was an error
int year = -1;
while (year != -1)
{
  PromptForYear();
  year = GetYear();
}
```

This code works with GetYear as follows:

```
int GetYear()
{
  int year;
  cin >> year;

  // check for bad year values
  if (year < 1583)
    return -1;

  return year;
}
```

And PromptForYear could be

```
void PromptForYear()
{
  cout << "\n\nPlease select a year after 1583 \n\n";
}
```

Personally I would prefer a TryGetYear method:

```
while (true)
{
  PromptForYear();
  if (TryGetYear(&year))
  {
    break;
  }
}

// code for TryGetYear

bool TryGetYear(int* year)
{
  if (year == null)
    return false;

  cin >> *year;
  if (*year < 1583)
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: `break` statements are frowned upon in programming classes (unless they're in a `switch`). Use a `do{}while` instead. Also makes the code clearer (no need for that extra `if`).

Comment: @trutheality yep, I was a TA, and I always felt the no-break preference was worthless. 10 years later in the field, I still feel this way. But meh .. whatever.

Comment: I have nothing against `break` statements to break loops, they can be pretty handy when without them you'd need to set up a bunch of boolean flags, but in this case I think the `do{}while` is actually more readable than the `break`.

Comment: i'll try ForYear method and how do i add this part  to the Foryear method? do i put this also in my function or do in the main program?
}
  if(Leap_year(year))//if statement calls Leap Year funtion
  {
       printf("\t =======================  \n");
       printf("\t*  THIS IS A LEAP YEAR  *\n");      
       printf("\t =======================  \n\n"); 
  }
  else {
       printf("\t   =======================  \n");
       printf("\t*  THIS IS NOT A LEAP YEAR  *\n");
       printf("\t   =======================  \n\n");

Comment: @trutheality now that this is really just a discussion of prefs :), I like while's for all non-iterative loops, else for's. I don't like do-whiles because they hide the condition and because a while(true) is just as clear (to me). Note: if you code reviewed my work and asked me to use a do-while, I would. Not a big deal.

Comment: @ShadowChaser when I TA'd this assignment (it is a becoming a classic homework assignment to teach about functions), the teachers also gave the students a diagram of the methods and which calls which; a help-guide for this very assignment. Did you get something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `goto` - Add an else

i.e.

```
  if(year < 1583) //considers if a year input is less than 1583 which is the starting year for this calendar 
  { 
          printf("\n\nPlease select a year after 1583 \n\n"); 
          system("cls"); 
  } 
  else
  { 
....
```

Comment: And how do you re-prompt for input again?  You still need a looping construct.

Comment: @EricJ. You're acting on different assumptions of where the `YEAR` label is. (I'm inclined to agree with your guess though.)

Comment: @EricJ - Did not mention in the question that a re-prompt is required. Just had a different assumption to the `YEAR` label and the format of the original code kinda implied that the person was missing the `else` statement.

Comment: @Ed: If you just add an else statement, you will flow into the leap year calculation, which is undefined prior to 1583.  So, while perhaps not explicitly stated, allowing program execution to continue seems unwise.

Comment: @EricJ. - The code in the question has been edited (by Shredder
) since I wrote my answer. It had extra braces that adding `else` made sense.